# How to create Country and City Dropdown in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, native

I'm creating a form where I ask user to select your country. Once he selects his `country` in the next field he select the `city` of the respective country and go ahead. How I can achieve this in react native.

Comment: Well, you have to lean first about state and effects

Comment: Try the link below to get a list of countries and cities,

https://www.npmjs.com/package/country-state-city

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Picker](https://reactnative.dev/docs/picker) component that comes by default in React Native (supports Android and iOS), or use any other 3rd party library.